# USB Debugging in Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a real Android device connected via USB to my computer. I am trying to deploy on it my application and then debug it.

I was looking at [these instructions which say:](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device)

*On the device, open the Settings app, select Developer options, and then enable USB debugging.*

This is probably trivial, but I don't understand how to get to the *USB debugging* option.

I went to *Settings*:

[image]

But I can not find it:
[image]

Have the menu options changed in Android Studio 3.1.3?

How can one enable *USB Debugging*?

Comment: You need want developer option on mobile?

Comment: read sentence carefully "On the device, open the Settings app, select Developer options, and then enable USB debugging." , `on Device` not on `android studio`.

Comment: you need to look settings in your mobile phone not in your android studio :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions you followed refers to the Android device, so the actions:

*On the device, open the Settings app, select Developer options, and then enable USB debugging*.

needs to be done on your phone, not on the Android Studio.
Indeed, if you don't see any Developer options in your settings, just tap Build number 7 times.

More info at:
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misread the instructions.
You need to enable the usb debugging in your android phone, not on the android studio :P

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The ways to enable USB Debugging mode, which is accounted for the key step in Android rooting process, vary from one Android version to another. USB Debugging is required by adb, which is used for rooting, backing up, installing a custom ROM, tacking screenshots from computer and more.

[Click HERE for the description](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the images you've uploaded neither in this nor in imgur.com.

But from what you ask, you should enable the developer settings first. Depending on your Android version and phone manufacturer, it may be in different places. Go to settings, then About. Find the build number. (I cannot give specifics since I cannot every phone). It should be easy though.

Once you have found it, start clicking on it, you'll get some toast messages. Once you are done it should say "You are now a developer" or sth like that.

After that go the main settings screen, find Developer Options and enable USB debugging. After it is done, you should see a notification that is not dismissable, saying USB Debugging enabled.

Now, you can use the right upper corner "Debug" options to debug the app and see the breakpoints and their details. Hope this was what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the USB Debugging option under Settings > Developer options. For Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default; use the following steps: On the device, go to Settings > About . Tap the Build number seven times to make Settings > Developer options available.